# Mount drive and cd into a folder

Tags: partitioning, mount, cd-command

I have my work files on a different drive. Every time I want to work on it, I have to click through files -> Other locations -> /dev/sda2. Then run the terminal in there. I am wondering if this is automatable?

What I have tried:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/username
cd /media/username/desiredFolder
```

The problem with my approach is when I run Sudo the password is needed which means the script can not run on its own. Is there a way to bypass that? Or perhaps a better way to accomplish the directory switch?

Comment: I've edited out the first sentence of your post because it's unnecessary (don't worry though, people aren't going to be mean to you even if you ask a stupid question! If they are, just flag it and it will be taken down)

Comment: You need to research how to add a new entry in your /etc/fstab file. That tells the system what to mount when it boots and where with what options. There are lots of articles available with a simple google search for “fstab” This is the first hit when I try this - https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/ Let us know how you get on. If you cannot work it out yourself add your UUID and filesystem type to the question and I’ll answer more precisely.